# Transferring files from Windows SSD to Linux SSD in the same PC?

Tags: linux, files, windows, virtual-machine

How would this scenario work: One PC with a Windows SSD and a separate Linux SSD. I want to run a Windows virtual machine within the Linux SSD. Transferring of files would only be done while booted in Windows SSD, to the Linux SSD (so from Windows, using Windows, to Linux). Then Linux would be booted and those transferred files copied and used in the virtual machine.

I doubt I could just copy and paste the files. If the Linux SSD had a NTFS partition, would Windows see it from the other drive?

Comment: If the Linux system must be offline for file transfer, you could look into an appropriate file system driver for Windows, such as https://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/. I cannot recommend it, though. UDF is also a good choice for both OSes. Personally, I would prefer shared folders (provided by the virtualisation solution, NFS, or Samba).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really run SSDs, you run Operating Systems (Windows and/or Linux in this instance). Each OS can use some or all of the available disk storage for its filesystem.

It's perfectly possible to run Windows as a VM on Linux. You can use part or all of an SSD as backing store for that Windows VM. (Either directly or as a file in the host filesystem.) With that VM and the host Linux system running you can transfer files between them using protocols such as CIFS/Samba or SSH.

However, it's probably going to be just as easy to copy files between the filesystems. Linux systems can read/write Windows filesystems reasonable successfully, and to some lesser extent windows can use third-party software Windows to read/write native Linux filesystems. Create an NTFS filesystem for your Linux-based system and Windows can read/write that directly. Just don't expect to read/write a filesystem directly from one OS that's actively being used by the other.

Comment: Network file sharing is 100% safe vs using an ext4 driver for Windows or an NTFS driver for Linux both of which have quirks and issues and may lead to data loss.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I wouldn't want to use ext2fsd at the moment, but the ntfs-3g driver seems reasonably solid

Comment: I've had severe FS corruptions while using NTFS-3g. Stopped using it except for retrieving/deleting files from my NTFS drives.